# Not able to use "Save" button in QGIS's Table Manager

Tags: qgis, shapefile, table, qgis-2.14

I'm getting a message that says "Failed backing up the old table to..." when I use the "Save" button Table Manager after deleteting fields from a shapefile. It says I should use "Save As..." instead, which is quite inconvenient. I'm using version 2.14.

---

Something I forgot to add is that in v. 2.8 and 2.10 this problem did not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the author of the plugin responded to a [bug ticket](https://trac.osgeo.org/qgis/ticket/3559) 5 years ago:

> "Seems it's a problem with access to nnn.dbf file, while it's already open by Qgis. As Qgis can't delete fields by the OGR Driver, Tablemanager has to modify it on his own.
>
> Unfortunately I have no idea how to do it easily in operating systems not supporting multiple access to file (and I have no plans to invest more time into this plugin, as it's been designed as a temporary solution). I disabled this button on windows. I know it's not a real solution, so any help is wellcome."

Unfortunately, the issue still occurs in the latest [v0.6.2](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/tablemanager/).

---

**Edit:**

I noticed that I also receive a second message immediately after saying:

> "Saving successful. The old table has been backed up as example.dbf~. Do you wish to keep the layer style?"

If you leave the message and go to your TEMP directory (for me it's `C:/Users/Me/AppData/Local/Temp/`), you will see the backup shapefile which has been correctly edited. **Move this out of the TEMP folder before you click *Yes* or *No* in the message otherwise the shapefile will get deleted.**

Ofcourse, this is a lot more hassle than just using the *Save As...* option.